# Duplicate primary index error when no duplicates seen

Tags: sql, indexing, teradata

I am attempting to run a report script that I put together a couple months back for the second time (quarterly report). I have reached a point in script where I require a unique primary index, specifically when attempting to create a table `MEMBER_DATA_2`. When I try to run that `CREATE VOLATILE TABLE`, I'm receiving a Teradata error "[2801] Duplicate unique primary key error in target table".

Normally this isn't a big deal. The script requires the `Member_ID` & `Encounter_Nbr` fields to be the unique primary key. So I copied the `CREATE` for `MEMBER_DATA_2`, removed the `UNIQUE` requirement from the primary index and called the resulting volatile table `TEMP`. I created `TEMP` I then ran the following

```
SELECT T.*, B.Cnt
FROM TEMP AS T
    JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Member_ID, Encounter_Nbr, COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM TEMP GROUP BY 1,2) AS B
        ON B.Member_ID= T.Member_ID
            AND B.Encounter_Nbr= T.Encounter_Nbr
            AND B.Cnt > 1
ORDER BY B.Cnt DESC, T.Member_ID, T.Encounter_Nbr
```

The issue is that the above script produced a null result set. So unless I'm missing something, the index IS unique and `MEMBER_DATA_2` should be created without receiving the error message.

For now I can just drop the `UNIQUE` from the `MEMBER_DATA_2`'s `CREATE` for this run through since I know the error is bosu, but I want to make sure I don't keep getting the bogus error on future runs.

Comment: Teradata throws unique primary key errors on SELECT statements? Something tells me the problem isn't with this section of code. But whatever comes before it to insert into your TEMP table.

Comment: The error isn't thrown on a `SELECT`, but a `CREATE VOLATILE TABLE`. The three input tables used in that `CREATE` are not required to be unique on their primary keys, but if the logic producing `TEMP` is setup correctly, I should be getting a unique key. If I truly didn't have a unique key, that would indeed be an error I'd need to fix (thus why I require the unique key), but since I'm not actually getting duplication I don't want to keep getting false positives.

Comment: While this doesn't solve your issue, you may find it easier to test for uniqueness on a SELECT by using Teradata's `QUALIFY` clause: `SELECT * FROM TEMP QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY member_id, encounter_nbr) > 1;` Give that a run and see if you get any results. If you do, then you have duplicates on your `member_id, encounter_nbr` key presented as the result set.

Comment: You can also force uniqueness using `QUALIFY` (although it's a bit of a sledgehammer): `SELECT * FROM temp QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY member_id, encounter_nbr ORDER BY 1) = 1` This will pick one of the random duplicates from `temp` for the result set.

Comment: Are you saying the select statement above returns no rows? That doesn't make sense, that can't cause a uniqueness violation.

Comment: I've updated the question for clarity, but to re-iterate, I'm receiving the error when I attempt to run a `CREATE VOLATILE TABLE`. The `SELECT` in the question is the script I used to test if the primary index was indeed unique (which it showed IS the case). As such, I'm hoping someone can clarify why Teradata erronueously thinks there is a non-unique value.

Comment: Can you try the QUALIFY JNevill proposed against the base Select? Maybe MEMBER_DATA_2 is created as MULTISET, but TEMP as SET?

Comment: Definitely not using MULTISET. As to the QUALIFY, that's out because I want the error when it's valid, and can't be arbitrarily forcing the uniqueness.

Comment: I can't see how inserting 0 rows can possibly cause a uniqueness violation, I have to think there is something else going on.

Comment: I'm not inserting, the CREATE table is based on a different SELECT statement that's not shown. The query that is shown is purely to test for instances where that CREATE's logic results in more than one instance of the primary key. Since that test query yielded no results, it seems like having that CREATE use UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX shouldn't be resulting in the error, and yet it does throw the error. Thus my confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, a coworker figured it out. The Encounter_Nbr is ending up NULL in some instances and that was hiding the offending members in my test query (due to the Encounter_Nbr = Encounter_Nbr JOIN condition failing).

On to figuring out why the Encounter_Nbr isn't populating correctly.